# Active class not working on custom menu link using add_menu_page

Tags: php, menus

i have created new custom menu that act like link to some page using this code:

```
add_menu_page( __( 'Gallery', '' ), __( 'Gallery', '' ), 'edit_posts', 'post.php?post='. $gallery_page_id .'&action=edit', '', 'dashicons-admin-gallery', 6 );
```

the problem is that, when i click on this link, active class become on "pages" and not on my custom menu link (i know this is part of pages).

the question is how to add active class to my custom link and remove from the "pages".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is quite a hack I propose, but I would suggest the following:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'chg_menu_on_special_pages_page' );
function chg_menu_on_special_pages_page(){
    global $parent_file;
    $gallery_page_id = 2;
    if( $parent_file != 'edit.php?post_type=page' )
        return;

    if( ! isset( $_GET['post'] ) || $_GET['post'] != $gallery_page_id )
        return;

    $parent_file = 'post.php?post='. $gallery_page_id .'&action=edit';
    return;
}
```

By the global `$parent_file` it is decided, which menu gets highlighted. We hook into the `admin_head`-action, the last action hook before the menu gets displayed. WordPress already decided, which is the `$parent_file`, in the case of your gallery it would be the "edit.php?post_type=page".

So, what do we do? We check if we are on our "Gallery"-Edit page and if so, we switch `$parent_file` to the URL, we've registered earlier using `add_menu_page()`. In my code, I was setting `$gallery_page_id = 2;` to test it.

Files in the admin, you might be interested in are `wp-admin/menu-header.php`. Variables, which you might be interested in are `$menu`, `$submenu`, `$parent_file`.

I hope, this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could define a function which just pulls in the post.php content and set it as your callback for add_menu_page().  But the slug parameter is not meant to accept variables.   You will need to modify the $_REQUEST array to achieve that.

Ex:

```
add_menu_page( __( 'Gallery', '' ), __( 'Gallery', '' ), 'edit_posts', 'gallery-edit', 'gallery-edit-page', 'dashicons-admin-gallery', 6 );
function gallery-edit-page() {
  $gallery_page_id = 0; // change to the ID of your gallery page
  $_REQUEST['post'] = $gallery_page_id;
  $_REQUEST['action'] = 'edit';
  include('post.php');
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this will break the ability to save changes to your custom page. Try it and let me know.